# Shared Preferences Android Stidop

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

Tive a ver um tuturial no youtube e copiei este código para guardar e apagar valores inseridos, a minha dúvida é que aparece sempre aquele "0" como tem abaixo e gostaria de saber como posso tira-lo sem dar erro, deixo também o código e é claro se houver outra forma mais fácil de usar o shared preferences.

```
.....int val1 = myprefs.getInt("keybanca",0);
        banca.setText(String.valueOf(val1));.....

----------------------------</>-------------------------------

public class Gestao extends AppCompatActivity {

 EditText banca, greens, reds, lucro, prejuizo, total, num1, num2, ano;
      TextView  total2;

    SharedPreferences myprefs;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_gestao);


        myprefs = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
        init();

    }


    public void back2(View view) {
        Intent back= new Intent(this, Menu.class);
        startActivity(back);
    }




    private void init() {
        banca = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
        greens = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        reds = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);
        lucro = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText4);
        prejuizo = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText5);
        total = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText6);
        num1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText13);
        num2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText14);
        total2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView16);
        ano = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText21);





        readPreferences();

    }

    public void onSave(View view){
        int bancaText =  Integer.parseInt(banca.getText().toString());
        int greensText = Integer.parseInt(greens.getText().toString());
        int redsText = Integer.parseInt(reds.getText().toString());
        int lucroText = Integer.parseInt(lucro.getText().toString());
        int prejuizoText = Integer.parseInt(prejuizo.getText().toString());
        int totalText = Integer.parseInt(total.getText().toString());
        int anoText = Integer.parseInt(ano.getText().toString());






        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = myprefs.edit();
        editor.putInt("keybanca", bancaText);
        editor.putInt("keygreens", greensText);
        editor.putInt("keyreds", redsText);
        editor.putInt("keylucro", lucroText);
        editor.putInt("keyprejuizo", prejuizoText);
        editor.putInt("keytotal",totalText);
        editor.putInt("keyano",anoText);

        editor.commit ();

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Guardado",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();



    }

    public void onReset (View view) {
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = myprefs.edit();
        editor.clear();
        editor.commit();
        readPreferences();

    }



    public void readPreferences()
    {

        int val1 = myprefs.getInt("keybanca",0);
        banca.setText(String.valueOf(val1));

        int val2 = myprefs.getInt("keygreens",0);
        greens.setText(String.valueOf(val2));

        int val3 = myprefs.getInt("keyreds", 0);
        reds.setText(String.valueOf(val3));

        int val4 = myprefs.getInt("keylucro",0);
        lucro.setText(String.valueOf(val4));

        int val5 = myprefs.getInt("keyprejuizo",0);
        prejuizo.setText(String.valueOf(val5));

        int val6 = myprefs.getInt("keytotal", 0);
        total.setText(String.valueOf(val6));

        int val7 = myprefs.getInt("keyano", 0);
        ano.setText(String.valueOf(val7));


    }
```

Comment: Você gostaria de null no lugar de 0? Se for isso, já que você quer guardar os valores como text e não faz nenhuma operação nos números como int, você poderia pegar diretamente o valor da preferência como String: `banca.setText(myprefs.getString("keybanca",null));`. O segundo argumento de getString() (ou getInt()) é o valor default para aquela propriedade, isto é, o valor retornado pelo método se ela não foi definida.

Comment: O meu objetivo é inserir apenas números e guardar dentro da EditText, mas da forma como tenho o código na EditText a correr a aplicação aparece sempre o "0" e eu não queria. Poderia editar o meu código dessa forma. Obrigado

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Voce pode fazer uma simples validacao antes de popular a EditText:

```
if (myprefs.getInt("keybanca",0) != 0){
    banca.setText(String.valueOf(val1));
} else {
    banca.setText("");
}
```

Comment: Não estou a conseguir ter sucesso através da sua resposta, poderá editar o meu código para eu tentar perceber melhor. Obrigado

Comment: Eu tentei editar mas aparentemente nao foi aceito, mas a ideia é verificar o resultado de myprefs.getInt("keybanca",0) no metodo readPreferences(). Se fica mais claro, vc pode guardar o resultado de myprefs.getInt("keybanca",0) e só usar o resultado na EditText se o resultado for diferente de zero.